# How to access BotUserData within a LUIS Dialog

Tags: botframework

I am using LUIS dialog , I have a need to access the user token which is stored in BotUserData and also set some values in ConversationData from within the LUIS Dialog.
Is there a way to access the same from within a LUIS Dialog?

Answer (score 0):

It works in the same way that in a IDialog. You need use context.UserData or context.ConversationData.

Comment: suchismita, did this help?